# Android Studio gradle build error: 'The first result of the daemon was empty.Most likely the process died immediately after connection'

Tags: android, android-studio

I was unable to build the 'Hello World' project with a fresh install of android studio. It consumes a huge amount of RAM (up to 10GB) when building and throws the following error in the end:

> Error:The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.'

A large number of threads like the following one are continuously created when building:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /home/wisatbff/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.10-all/a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-launcher-2.10.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 2.10
```

I have no idea about what is going on. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**: Running `./gradlew build` from command line builds successfully.

**Environment**

OS: Arch Linux, kernel version 4.5.1
Android Studio: 2.1
jdk: 1.8.0_92

**gradle daemon log**

```
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] start() called on daemon - DefaultDaemonContext[uid=baa60fb9-2eee-4be9-b120-a0e0c330dbae,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk,daemonRegistryDir=/home/wisatbff/.gradle/daemon,pid=21023,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] updating lastActivityAt to 1462006862641
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface eth0
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:325a:3aff:fe05:9727%eth0
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface eth0
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface ppp0
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /10.170.52.241
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface ppp0
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface lo
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? true
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
[org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector] Listening on [4955d895-4319-4666-9fb0-4bfe4f133b0f port:40185, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]].
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] Daemon starting at: Sat Apr 30 17:01:02 CST 2016, with address: [4955d895-4319-4666-9fb0-4bfe4f133b0f port:40185, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]]
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DomainRegistryUpdater] Advertising the daemon address to the clients: [4955d895-4319-4666-9fb0-4bfe4f133b0f port:40185, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]]
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DomainRegistryUpdater] Advertised daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=baa60fb9-2eee-4be9-b120-a0e0c330dbae,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk,daemonRegistryDir=/home/wisatbff/.gradle/daemon,pid=21023,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Storing daemon address: [4955d895-4319-4666-9fb0-4bfe4f133b0f port:40185, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]], context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=baa60fb9-2eee-4be9-b120-a0e0c330dbae,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk,daemonRegistryDir=/home/wisatbff/.gradle/daemon,pid=21023,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] Daemon server started.
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonStartupCommunication] Completed writing the daemon greeting. Closing streams...
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] requestStopOnIdleTimeout(10800000 MILLISECONDS) called on daemon
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Idle timeout: waiting for daemon to stop or be idle for 10800000ms
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Daemon is idle, sleeping until state change or idle timeout at Sat Apr 30 20:01:02 CST 2016
```

**Android Studio log**

```
2016-04-30 17:45:58,067 [    128]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,075 [    136]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-143.2790544, 22 Apr 2016 00:00) 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,076 [    137]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Linux (4.5.1-1-arch, amd64) 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,076 [    137]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_92-b14 (Oracle Corporation) 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,076 [    137]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.92-b14 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,077 [    138]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/wisatbff/android-studio/bin/../lib/boot.jar -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -da -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/wisatbff/android-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/wisatbff/java_error_in_STUDIO_%p.log -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.1 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,077 [    138]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext: [cldrdata.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, meta-index, localedata.jar, dnsns.jar, sunec.jar, zipfs.jar, nashorn.jar, jaccess.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, jfxrt.jar] 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,089 [    150]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 12 ms 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,178 [    239]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - WM detected: awesome 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,187 [    248]   INFO - llij.openapi.wm.impl.X11UiUtil - impersonated WM: SAWFISH_WM 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,363 [    424]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,606 [    667]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 30 plugins initialized in 326 ms 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,607 [    668]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android NDK Support (1.0), Android Support (10.2.1), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (143.SNAPSHOT), EditorConfig (1.0), Google Analytics Uploader (1.0), Google App Indexing (0.1), Google Login (1.0), Google Services (0.1), Gradle (143.SNAPSHOT), Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java (143.SNAPSHOT), IDEA CORE (143.SNAPSHOT), IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (0.1), Properties Support (143.SNAPSHOT), SDK Updater (1.0), Settings Repository (143.SNAPSHOT), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0) 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,607 [    668]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Disabled plugins: CVS Integration (11), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (143.SNAPSHOT), Google Cloud Testing (1.0), Google Cloud Tools Core (0.2.8), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Subversion Integration (1.1), hg4idea (10.0) 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,914 [    975]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1286340608 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,942 [   1003]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: /home/wisatbff/android-studio/bin/fsnotifier64 
2016-04-30 17:45:58,947 [   1008]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2016-04-30 17:45:59,418 [   1479]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2016-04-30 17:45:59,846 [   1907]   INFO - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/sources/android-23/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:00,047 [   2108]   INFO - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/tools/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:00,054 [   2115]   INFO - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:00,060 [   2121]   INFO - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:00,065 [   2126]   INFO - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:00,071 [   2132]   INFO - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:00,076 [   2137]   INFO - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:00,245 [   2306]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 82 application components initialized in 1966 ms 
2016-04-30 17:46:00,260 [   2321]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 3010 ms 
2016-04-30 17:46:00,990 [   3051]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 4 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,496 [   3557]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 136 project components initialized in 797 ms 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,496 [   3557]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,654 [   3715]   INFO - android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/sources/android-23/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,659 [   3720]   INFO - android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/tools/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,663 [   3724]   INFO - android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,667 [   3728]   INFO - android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,671 [   3732]   INFO - android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,681 [   3742]   INFO - android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,686 [   3747]   INFO - android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,696 [   3757]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/sources/android-23/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,712 [   3773]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/tools/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,723 [   3784]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,728 [   3789]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'My First App'. 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,733 [   3794]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,741 [   3802]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,746 [   3807]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,752 [   3813]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Parsing /home/wisatbff/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/package.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,784 [   3845]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,897 [   3958]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /usr/lib/jvm/default 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,898 [   3959]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /usr/lib/jvm/default 
2016-04-30 17:46:01,930 [   3991]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Maven repo at '/home/wisatbff/android-studio/gradle/m2repository' 
2016-04-30 17:46:02,052 [   4113]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:02,094 [   4155]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - /home/wisatbff/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp/.idea/misc.xml case-sensitivity: true 
2016-04-30 17:46:02,577 [   4638]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:02,645 [   4706]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, /tmp/asLocalRepo7.gradle, --init-script, /tmp/ijinit7.gradle] 
2016-04-30 17:46:02,878 [   4939]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 0ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2016-04-30 17:46:02,916 [   4977]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:02,929 [   4990]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 50ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2016-04-30 17:46:03,021 [   5082]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 2369 ms 
2016-04-30 17:46:03,030 [   5091]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-04-30 17:46:03,033 [   5094]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-04-30 17:46:03,037 [   5098]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-04-30 17:46:03,039 [   5100]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-04-30 17:46:03,141 [   5202]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2016-04-30 17:46:03,217 [   5278]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:03,509 [   5570]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:03,858 [   5919]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:04,324 [   6385]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon2-1-x86.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:04,595 [   6656]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:04,971 [   7032]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:05,263 [   7324]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:05,551 [   7612]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:05,867 [   7928]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:06,144 [   8205]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:06,422 [   8483]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:06,886 [   8947]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:07,169 [   9230]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /home/wisatbff/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
2016-04-30 17:46:07,169 [   9230]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-12.xml 
2016-04-30 17:46:07,490 [   9551]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml 
2016-04-30 17:47:31,825 [  93886]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation '/home/wisatbff/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.10'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:339)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:230)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.NoUsableDaemonFoundException: Unable to find a usable idle daemon. I have connected to 100 different daemons but I could not use any of them to run build: Build{id=acdc7e86-d815-4916-b4b6-ccb3e714b458.1, currentDir=/home/wisatbff/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp}.  BuildActionParameters were DefaultBuildActionParameters{, currentDir=/home/wisatbff/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp, systemProperties size=90, envVariables size=38, logLevel=LIFECYCLE, daemonUsage=IMPLICITLY_DISABLED, continuous=false, interactive=false, injectedPluginClasspath=[]}.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:135)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:132)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:117)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:190)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:105)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonInitialConnectException: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:154)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:125)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning restarting and rebuilding? that's the first thing I do when errors from nowhere occurs/

Comment: @Anders Yes. I've even reinstalled all the things but still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. Since I'm behind the GFW, I need to use a proxy in order to download things like Android SDK. I used proxychains and maybe I got the configuration for localnet exclusion wrong which stops gradle from connecting to the daemon.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by removing a masquerade rule from my postrouting NAT table.

```
[root@me]: iptables -t nat -L
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
[root@me]: iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1
```

I still have other MASQUERADING rules in that table but they have specific source address masks rather than source "anywhere".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after Android Studio closed unexpectedly. Solved it by doing `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: Didn't help me AND I lost all my local history.

Comment: @FractalBob You don't downvote an answer because it didn't help YOU

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in **Android Studio 3**.However, none of the solutions mentioned here worked for me.With only **4 GB of RAM** available ,the only thing worked for me was just changing the value specified for JVM args which is related to RAM in **gradle.properties** file like the following:

```
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

to:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m
```

then File | Invalidate Caches/Restart--> Invalidate and Restart

This really did the trick.