# Gradle sync failed: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I just recently downloaded an Android Studio and installed it on my PC. But When I try to set up my first project "hello world", it always brings up the following:

> Gradle sync failed: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.
>   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: What did you find in the IDE logs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio gradle build error 'the first result of the daemon was empty'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953380/android-studio-gradle-build-error-the-first-result-of-the-daemon-was-empty)

Comment: If not a proxy setting, then please [edit] to show the logs

Answer (score 70):

I solved the problem by doing the following:

1. go to `C:/Users/.../.gradle/daemon/`
2. open any of the folders in `daemon`
3. look for this file `registry.bin.lock`
4. delete it
5. now go sync the gradle in Android Studio and your problem will be solved

**Success**

Comment: In macOS location of `registry.bin.lock` file is: `~/.gradle/daemon/{gradle_version}/`

Comment: bro tip: running `del registry.bin.lock /s` inside the daemon directory will delete all `registry.bin.lock`s for all gradle versions

Comment: Very Good Method, Thanks Man!

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem in **Android Studio 3**.However, none of the solutions mentioned here worked for me.With only **4 GB of RAM** available ,the only thing worked for me was just changing the value specified  for  JVM args which is related to RAM in **gradle.properties** file like the following:

```
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

to:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m
```

then File | Invalidate Caches/Restart--> Invalidate and Restart

This really did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Guess what, I just faced this issue and I solved it. 
I did something very risky, but it looks like the fault is in the gradle cache directory. 
If you are using windows the dir. will be at C:\Users\username.....gradle\caches and deamon <- will be the directory where all the gradle versions are stored. Delete the latest particular version from the Cache as well as the Deamon folder. Next time your project syncs, AS will automatically generate the two files.
Also
3.Now go to android studio - File ->invalidate Cache/Restart 4.Now edit gradle-wrapper.properties and add latest version of gradle there.After updation my gradle-wrapper.properties looked like this. From the above answer. This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Today I faced the same issue. File-Invalidate & Restart worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First Credit Goes to Kali Kimanzi .. 
for this answer [Windows 7-10]

> go to C:/Users/.../.gradle/daemon/
>       open any of the folders in daemon
>       look for this file registry.bin.lock
>       delete it
>       now go sync the gradle in Android Studio and your problem should be solved

A little update for noobs .. C:/Users//.gradle/daemon/
and instead of deleting the file registry.bin.lock just rename it to registry.bin.lock.backup just incase .. though the file itself might be corrupt

Answer (score 0):

1. Just look **gradle-wrapper.properties** from project opened inside android studio.
   **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip**
2. Now to go **C:\Users.gradle\wrapper\dists** there you can see different gradle versions.I'm my case I had a latest version gradle-2.11-all.
3. Now go to android studio - File ->invalidate Cache/Restart
4. Now edit **gradle-wrapper.properties** and add latest version of gradle there.After updation my **gradle-wrapper.properties** looked like this.

   ```
   distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-all.zip
   ```

Now Sync project. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem.I exited from Android Studio and re-opened Android Studio.In my case,The Problem Solved Then.You Can Try this Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** The only workaround for me is to use ipv6 instead of ipv4 : in **bin/studio.vmoptions** or **bin/studio64.vmoptions** (*depending on if you are in 32 or 64 bits*), change the line

- Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

by

- Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=true

Answer (score 0):

If any of the cases mentioned here didn't meet the expectations, there may be something wrong with your `dnsapi.dll` file in your windows which several software use (It happens in rare cases but give it a try).

Close Android Studio and try running a program(software) that uses this `dnsapi.dll` file. For ex. try running BitTorrent. If it says `'DNSapi.dll missing from your computer'`, then the studio error is most probably because of the corrupted/missing dll file.

Try running following command on your command prompt.(**Make sure you have a good internet connection**)

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

And then run the system file checker.

```
sfc /scannow
```

It would take some time.
Now run Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the other answer but I couldn't find the **registry.bin.lock** file in mac, then I just deleted the following folders,'

- **/Users/../.gradle/caches**
- **/Users/../.gradle/daemon**

then do a File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart.
The above folders should be updated during Gradle Sync, just say yes if it throws popup for gradle update

Please take a backup of these folders before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after trying all of the above, I realised:

- I was using the wifi network @ brandname coffeshop which had authentification.
- I also had Global Gradle settings:"Offline work" activated (Settings/Build,Execution,Deployment/Gradle/Global Gradle settings).

I switched to my phone hotspot, and deactivated the Offline work.

Now (after 1 and a half hours) my builds are running again.

Answer (score 0):

Sitting on MacOs 10.14.6 tried these things:

- Close/Open Android Studio
- Invalidate caches/Restart
- Download latest NDK from Tools/SDK Manager
- Delete all NDKs from mac

Nothing helped. The only worked is **reset Mac**

Still dont know what caused this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

**To find the actual issue:**

You'll need to look into the output logs of your daemons in: `~/.gradle/daemon/X.X.X/daemon-XXXXXXX.out.log`. Then search for line with `[ERROR]`.

One liner: `grep '\[ERROR\]' ~/.gradle/daemon/*/daemon*.out.log`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in IntelliJ. I fixed it by running the following command in the terminal:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Answer (score -2):

Now the answers given before me are quite technical, mine is the exact opposite. What worked for me everytime this issue came in, was checking my internet connection. Once I was connected to my mobile hotspot instead of my regular wifi, and I was getting this issue. I have no idea why, but reconnecting to my wifi fixed it. I didnt restart the IDE or anything. I'm sure there is some technical explanation behind this, but as long as it works, I am fine lol.

Comment: Yes, a bad internet connection will not allow you to use internet properly. This is not new information.