# I am facing Gradle Issue

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I am a newbie in Android development and when I reach to Gradle Sync after setting up my android ap name and version then it shows " Gradle Syncing" and after a while it shows this error : "The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection. "
Plz help. I have an active internet connection. Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle sync failed: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431565/gradle-sync-failed-the-first-result-from-the-daemon-was-empty-most-likely-the)

Comment: Also please have a read on the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It should improve your chances to get an answer and avoid downvotes.