# Android Studio 3.0.1 Gradle issue (Error: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have recently been encountering this issue to the point where I cannot continue working. When starting Android Studio Gradle builds as normal but as soon as daemon starts it fails and I get the Error:

> The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.

I have done a number of different things and I have searched all over the internet trying to find a solution for this issue so I can work on some projects I have but so far I have not had any luck. A few of the links I tried using to find a solution are:

- [Android Studio gradle build error: 'The first result of the daemon was empty.Most likely the process died immediately after connection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953380/android-studio-gradle-build-error-the-first-result-of-the-daemon-was-empty-mos)
- [Gradle sync failed: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431565/gradle-sync-failed-the-first-result-from-the-daemon-was-empty-most-likely-the)
- https://teamtreehouse.com/community/first-result-from-daemon-was-empty-gradle-build-continues-to-fail
- https://www.jianshu.com/p/5891e7d46f6c

I have tried everything in those links and no matter what I do it does not work. I was so desperate to the point where I uninstalled Android Studio Gradle and all the SDK hoping that would fix it and that didn't do it either. I figured hey maybe it's another issue so I thought doing a clean install would do the trick and guess what it worked for a day or two and right after that back to the same place I started at now... (Worst part is I had to download over 200gb for the clean install due to all of the things I had to reinstall).

I am attaching a picture below in case anyone wants to see the original Gradle:

[Android Studio Gradle Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EQhY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after installing and reinstalling the operating system and everything on it about 4 different times. So the issue was the network driver and the software it seems like. Every time after the network driver is updated using driver website it crashes and renders the network useless.

After a while looking at the logs I finally noticed a pattern that Gradle was having issues with something involving the actual network adapters and so what I did was uninstall the network software and uninstall all of my network adapters driver and restarted the computer and had Windows 10 reinstall the drivers. I opened the Android Studio and it works flawlessly. So at the end of the day, the basics saved the day.

In case anyone is wondering which network devices I have they are the:

> Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet & Killer Wireless-n AC 1535 Network Adapter

The software is the killer network manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Killer network interface. The motherboard I'm using has 2 gigabit NICs and a wireless adapter built into it. One of the two gigabit ports is Intel.

I believe the problem is with the Killer gigabit port/ Drivers. To get around it I just disabled the Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet port and restarted Windows. Gradle and Android Studio are now working without issues.

Also the mobo I'm using is a Gigabyte X299 Aorus Gaming 7.

Answer (score 0):

Seems they fixed it with the latest Killer driver:
"KillerPerformanceSuite_1.5.1847_Win7_Win81_Win10_x64"

Just tested it and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and the culprit was also Killer-related software as mentioned in the other answers, after uninstall the software (from Store and through the Control Panel), then uninstalling the drivers, then restarting.

Then, it started to work again, but I just randomly decided to try installing the Killer Drivers+Software again through `KillerPerformanceSuite_2.0.1175_UWD_x64`, but it broke Gradle again, so I decide to do all those steps again, but after uninstalling the software (through Control Panel), I decided to check Android Studio if it would sync properly this time, and it did.

So the culprit might actually just be the software (Killer Network Manager).